# What punitive powers, if any, does a modern day Beit Din posses?

Tags: money, beit-din-court

If a person is summoned to a Beit Din today for a legal or monetary dispute and refuses to come to the Beit Din or participate in the process in any way, what punitive powers does a Beit Din in America posses to either compel participation or punish someone who refuses to come to their court?

Comment: IMHO to have a power it has to have a recognized community. Outside a community, no BD has any power as they are not chosen by anyone, they only do arbitration, if agreed upon.